# how to change color of variable and new text using append javascript

Tags: javascript, html, macros, confluence

I want to count the number of checked tasks at the end of every column in the table and display it on the last row but in green and then do the same for unchecked and display it in red.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
AJS.toInit(function() {
    var tables = $('table').has('.inline-task-list');
    tables.each(function() {
        var table = $(this);

        //calculates rows checked count
        if (table.find('tr').has('.inline-task-list').eq(0).find('.inline-task-list').length > 1) {
            table.find('tr').has('.inline-task-list').each(function() {
                var row = $(this);
                var tasks = row.find('li[data-inline-task-id]');
                var checkedCount = tasks.filter('.checked').length;
                var uncheckedCount = tasks.length - checkedCount;
                row.find('td').last().append(checkedCount + ' Company Task Completed ' + ' <br> ');
                row.find('td').last().append(uncheckedCount + '<strong> Company Task Remaining </storng>');
            });
        }

        //calculates columns checked count
        table.find('tr:eq(0) th').each(function(i) {
            var tasks = table.find('tr').find('td:eq(' + i + ') li[data-inline-task-id]');
            if (tasks.length > 1) {
                var checkedCount = tasks.filter('.checked').length;
                var uncheckedCount = tasks.length - checkedCount;
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).append(checkedCount + ' Company Task Completed ' + '<br>');
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).append(uncheckedCount + '<strong> Company Task Remaining </storng>');                  
            }
        });
    });
});
})(AJS.$);
```

I did try to change the color by doing the the following below, but I realize I am only changing the all of it to green then red. I cant manage to isolate the text strings to change them individually.

```
var uncheckedCount = tasks.length - checkedCount;
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).append(checkedCount + ' Company Task Completed ' + '<br>');
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).css('color','green');
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).append(uncheckedCount + '<strong> Company Task Remaining </storng>');
                    table.find('tr').last().find('td').eq(i).css('color','red');
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code currently? Also it doesn't seem you posted the completely give the relevant code (*missing closing brackets*).

Comment: Add your css and html too...

Comment: As mentioned before, we need more context here, please add further details.

Comment: I have updated to include full code. Currently after I append "# Company task completed" and "# Company Tasks Remaining" I have only managed to change all of it to red or green. I am trying to split it up and change the former green and the latter red.